# Getting Error parsing Haxe version "" when starting Visual Studio Code (Kode Studio)

Tags: visual-studio-code, haxe, kha

Found that the bug is reported from this block of the server.js in visual studio code's Haxe Language Server.

```
if(!haxeLanguageServer_HaxeServer.reVersion.match(output)) {
    var params2 = { type : 1, message : "Error parsing Haxe version " + JSON.stringify(output)};
    var message2 = { jsonrpc : "2.0", method : "window/showMessage"};
    if(params2 != null) {
        message2.params = params2;
    }
    _gthis.context.protocol.writeMessage(message2);
    return;
}
```

It renders me unable to build, where I get 'Error Compilation Failed.' It doesn't appear to be project dependant as all of my projects from https://github.com/jrdoughty/Kha-examples seem to get it, all of which have been in working order before.

Comment: You say it was working "before" - did anything in your setup change since then?

Comment: Sorry been a heck of a week... 

The only thing that I can think of that 'changed' really was I'd run 'sudo apt-get update' somewhat recently, which may have updated haxe. However, I don't believe Kode Studio utilizes anything it doesn't come with (as in it has its haxe and kha built in I think), so I'm not sure that that is it (plus removing it made no difference).

Comment: I'm trying to think of anything else, but nothing else comes to mind. My Macbook has been running the same version of Kode Studio with no problems as well on the same project.

Comment: Hey, just stumbled upon this. Do you still get that error? Is this only on Linux? It should output which version of Kha it uses while compiling, is that one up to date?